# How to keep the order of matches

Tags: postgresql

I have a name like this: **'Foo[1].Bar.Baz[2].Foo.Bar.Bar[3]'** where I want to extract the digits in square braces as an array **{1,2,3}**.

Currently I have something ugly like this:

```
select array_agg(digit) as digits from 
(select unnest(regexp_matches) as digit from 
(select * from regexp_matches('Foo[1].Bar.Baz[2].Foo.Bar.Bar[3]', '\[(\d+)\]', 'g')) t1) t2;
```

Unfortunately if there are more fields and a group by the order of the lines get mixed up.

Is there a way to do this?

The full statement looks like this (it only would need to run once to migrate some data).

```
select device_tag_name, new_digits from
(select device_tag_id_pk, device_tag_name, array_agg(digit) as new_digits, dht.hmi_tag_id_pk, dht.digits as digits from (
select device_tag_id_pk,device_tag_name, unnest(regexp_matches(device_tag_name, '\[(\d+)\]', 'g')::int[]) as digit from "dim_DeviceTags" ddt) as subquery
join "map_HMIDevice" mhd on mhd.device_tag_id_fk = subquery.device_tag_id_pk
join "dim_HMITags" dht on mhd.hmi_tag_id_fk = dht.hmi_tag_id_pk 
group by device_tag_id_pk, device_tag_name, dht.digits, dht.hmi_tag_id_pk) as t
where new_digits != digits;
```

The result would look like this:

```
    |device_tag_name                        |new_digits |
    |---------------------------------------|-----------|
    |Extr[1].Hzne[8].Ctrl.MF.Max.OA_Cnvl[4] |{8,1,4}    |
    |Extr[1].Hzne[8].Ctrl.MF.Max.OA_Cnvl[3] |{1,3,8}    |
    |Extr[1].Hzne[8].Ctrl.MF.Max.OA_Cnvl[2] |{8,2,1}    |
    |Extr[1].Hzne[8].Ctrl.MF.Max.OA_Cnvl[1] |{8,1,1}    |
    |Extr[1].Hzne[8].Ctrl.MF.Max.OA_Cnvl[2] |{8,2,1}    |
    |Extr[1].Hzne[8].Ctrl.MF.Max.OA_Cnvl[1] |{8,1,1}    |
```

Comment: Could you provide an example where the order gets mixed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `WITH ORDINALITY` to the regexp_matches, then use that ordinality columnto order in the aggregate.

```
select array_agg(digit order by ordinality desc) as digits from 
(select unnest(regexp_matches) as digit, ordinality from 
(select * from regexp_matches('Foo[1].Bar.Baz[2].Foo.Bar.Bar[3]', '\[(\d+)\]', 'g') with ordinality) t1) t2;
```

Note that I reversed the order of the sorting, so that the result would be visually distinguishable from the original result, for testing/demo purposes.

Your UNNEST is unneeded here.  Since you only have one capturing group in the regexp, your resulting match array always has exactly one value.  So rather than unnesting it, you can simply index into the array with square bracets to get out the sole value:

```
select array_agg(digit order by ordinality desc) as digits from 
(select regexp_matches[1] as digit, ordinality from regexp_matches('Foo[1].Bar.Baz[2].Foo.Bar.Bar[3]', '\[(\d+)\]', 'g') with ordinality) t1;
```

Comment: I ended up with something like
`select ddt.device_tag_id_pk, ddt.device_tag_name, array_agg(trim(d.digit[1],'[]')::int order by d.ord) as new_digits from "dim_DeviceTags" ddt
left join lateral regexp_matches(ddt.device_tag_name, '(\[(\d+)\]|\d{2})(\.|$)', 'g') with ordinality as d(digit, ord) on true
group by ddt.device_tag_id_pk, ddt.device_tag_name`

I added the lateral join because I couldn't find another way to match on a table field.